# Ubuntu environment variable is not visible in weblogic start script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, weblogic, upstart

So I'm configuring weblogic on Ubuntu, I made a system user "weblogic" and added `MW_HOME` and `WL_HOME` environment variables in `/etc/profile.d`

I can echo them all right. I'm trying to set weblogic to start with upstart and I'm using

```
start-stop-daemon --start -u weblogic -c weblogic:weblogic --exec $MW_HOME/wlserver/server/bin/startNodeManager.sh
```

here's the error message I get:

```
/opt/Middleware/wlserver/server/bin/startNodeManager.sh: 42: .: Can't open /wlserver/../oracle_common/common/bin/commEnv.sh
```

and here's the script line 42:

```
WL_HOME="${MW_HOME}/wlserver"
. "${WL_HOME}/../oracle_common/common/bin/commEnv.sh"
```

so the message suggests that `$MW_HOME` is empty. WHY?

Comment: When "upstarting" some task the effective users account does not go through the login predure. Therefore things defined to be setup during such a login are not present. here your environment variables. Note that there is a difference between opening a shell and opening a _login_ shell. Why do you want to define those values in the accounts profile settings? When not whilst starting the deamon which is where such tasks are usually done?

Comment: Ah, so profile.d are only executed for login shells? Should I move the variables to /etc/environment?

Comment: Correct, stuff in `/etc/.profile.d` only gets executed during a login, when a login shell is created. You _could_ do that manually using something like `bash -l .....`, but why? Also `/etc/environment` is not the best idea where. I mean in the end you are _not_ trying to set those values _for all users and sessions_ in that system. Best is to either create a wrapper script which can "prepare" the command in whichever way you like, or use account specific scripts like `.bashrc` et all.